# Maximum total score from table with elimination

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

Imagine you have an n-by-m grid populated with positive values. You pick min(n,m) squares from the grid, eliminating the row and column of the square when you pick it. Your score is then the some of the values in the squares you picked. I'm trying to find the maximum possible score. Is there any way to do this other than going through all the possibilities?  If I have to enumerate through everything, what's the most efficient way to do that? I'm trying to implement this in python if that makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "picking squares from the grid"?

Comment: Please post some examples of what you have tried already code-wise

Comment: This is equivalent to [finding a maximum matching in a weighted bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs). Look at the algorithms for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to [finding a maximum matching in a weighted bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs). Rows and columns correspond to nodes of the graph, and if `table[u][v]` has a nonzero value `x`, then there's an edge between row node u and column node v with weight x. The edges selected in a maximum matching correspond to the nonzero cells to pick; if there are less than `min(n, m)` edges in the matching, the remaining options for table cells all have value zero, so you can pick the remaining cells arbitrarily. (If the table can have negative entries, you'll have to adjust all table entries upward to make sure all entries are nonnegative before constructing the graph.)

Graph libraries like [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching) and [igraph](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#maximum_bipartite_matching) offer implementations of weighted maximum matching algorithms, so you can convert your table to a graph and delegate the difficult work to the library.

Comment: The one part I'm not sure about is your parenthetical about negative entries...  If you add some constant c to all weights, this can increase the *number* of edges in a maximum weighted matching, even if all weights were positive to start with (since each additional edge awards another c points), so I'm not sure that optimality is retained by doing this.  Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The questioner needs to pick `min(n, m)` grid cells, which corresponds to always picking a max-cardinality matching (if you materialize the zero-weight edges I eliminated as a possibly-premature optimization). All such matchings have their weight affected equally by adding a constant to all table entries.

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting that this particular bipartite graph is complete, so if all edges have positive weight then the max-weight matching will necessarily have min(n, m) edges.  I'd suggest adding "complete" into your answer, for the next "me" who comes along ;)